# Как посчитать среднее значение по условию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Есть таблица people в ней столбцы `ID`,  `Sex`. Есть таблица `cars` имеющая столбцыID  `ID_person` и `Price`.

Как посчитать среднюю цену только для владельцев со значением `Seх = "м"`?

Я пробовал взять все индексы:

```
result = data_people.Sex[data_people.Sex == 'м'].index.tolist()
```

Потом:

```
result2 = (data_cars.merge(data_people.Sex[data_people.Sex == 'м'].index ,left_on="ID_person", right_on="ID",suffixes=["", "_2"]).mean("Price") )
```

```
 ID      Name         Height   Weight          Sex
  1 Журавлёвa Ия       184      40              ж
  2 Пестовa Снежана    183      40              ж
  3 Исаков Андрей      184      41              м
  4 Зуевa Альбина      179      40              ж
  5 Горбунов Сергей    183      41              м
```

```
 ID  ID_person Model   Price
  0    5       LADA    100000
  1    2      Toyota   50000
  2    1      Toyota   600000
  3    3      Daewoo   65000
  4    4      Subaru   300000
```

Получить надо среднее значение от 100000 и 65000.

Как получить эту одну цифру?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1:

```
In [9]: cars.merge(pers.rename(columns={"ID":"ID_person"})).groupby("Sex")["Price"].mean()
Out[9]:
Sex
ж    316666.666667
м     82500.000000
Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

Вариант 2:

```
In [10]: cars.merge(pers.query("Sex == 'м'").rename(columns={"ID":"ID_person"})).groupby("Sex")["Price"].mean()
Out[10]:
Sex
м    82500
Name: Price, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Как то все очень сложно.
Почему бы не сделать примерно вот так:

```
.....['Price'].mean()
```

или так

```
... .Price.mean()
```

и будет вам "одна цифра".